# RequestHandler: Is my code clean?

Tags: php, object-oriented

I've built a simple class `RequestHandler` that does exactly what I want without any extras I won't be utilizing. When needed I will expand. I'm passing this object to my Router class, to route URls to the correct controller. I will also take any suggestions!

**How is the readability?**

**Good idea to make it a singleton?** There will always be 1 request to process at a time.

**What about dependency injection?** I didn't utilize dependency injection with this class. How else would I get the URI without using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or any other similar `$_SERVER` variable. So I don't see why I would inject it, while there are no other ways.

```
class RequestHandler
{
    private $rawUri;
    private $cleanUri;
    private $method;
    private $controller;
    private $action;
    private $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->rawUri   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $this->cleanUri = preg_replace(['#/+#', '(\.\./)'], '/', trim($this->rawUri, '/'));
        $this->method   = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

        $this->parseUri();
    }

    private function parseUri()
    {
        //parse "/controller/action/param1/param2/..." format
        $parts = explode('/', $this->cleanUri);
        $parts = array_filter($parts);

        sort($parts);

        if ($parts) {
            $this->controller = ucfirst(array_shift($parts)) . 'Controller';
            $this->action     = array_shift($parts);
            $this->params     = ($parts) ? $parts : null;
        }
    }

    public function getRawUri()
    {
        return $this->rawUri;
    }

    public function getCleanUri()
    {
        return $this->cleanUri;
    }

    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    public function getController()
    {
        return $this->controller;
    }

    public function getAction()
    {
        return $this->action;
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick observation I have made here, and this is by no means a full review, but you have some dead code here:

```
if ($parts) {
    $this->controller = ucfirst(array_shift($parts)) . 'Controller';
    $this->action     = array_shift($parts);
    $this->params     = ($parts) ? $parts : null;
}
```

It will only enter the if-block if `$parts` is true, and when assigning to `$this->params` you check it again, but it can never be `null`.

Therefore you should just assign `$this->params = $parts;`

Overall the readability of the code looks fine to me.